# Android Studio release build not zipaligning

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk, android-studio-2.2

I'm having trouble uploading my .apk to Google Play Store. I've previously been able to upload multiple different builds up to last week, but today I get the error that I should zipalign my file first.

*EDIT*: Normally, I was able to generate signed and zipaligned .apk's that the AppStore accepted by just using Android Studios built-in "Generate Signed APK" wizard. This did not work today, and led to the following:

**I've tried the following**:

- **Manual zipalign** of the app-release.apk generated by Android studio. When I try this, I get the error "VERIFICATION FAILED" at the end. Some googling says that providing full path to a location where you have write-access is important, so I've tried doing it with the specific path, but to no avail:

  `./zipalign -v -f 4 /Users/<username>/git/<projectname>/app/app-release.apk /Users/<username>/git/<projectname>/app/aligned.apk`
- I then tried to download the **APK Signer 1.8.5** and use that to zipalign the .apk - and behold, success! It creates an aligned apk, and i'm able to verify it using both Android Studio's own zipalign tool by

  `./zipalign -c -v 4 app-release_ALIGNED.apk`

  and the APK Signer itself. However, when uploading I now get the error:

  `Failed to run aapt dump badging:
  W/ResourceType(208730): Bad resource table: header size 0x80a3 or total size 0x80b50000 is larger than data size 0x7bcc4
  ERROR: dump failed because the resource table is invalid/corrupt.`

  This, I haven't been able to find solutions for.
- I then tried to **recreate the circumstances** I was previously able to upload APKs from by reverting to a previous commit/build, as well as reverting from AS 2.2 preview 3 to AS2.2 preview 2, but again - no luck.
- Finally, I tried explicitly adding

  `zipAlignEnabled true`

  to my release config in Gradle, but that didn't help either.

I'm out of suggestions, and hoping someone can help? :-) Thanks

Comment: Why do you make your life so hard. Just go in Android Studio to Build -> Generate Signed APK then select your Keystore and insert all passwords and then let it generate.  You will find the generated aok in your app folder.

Comment: My bad, I didn't specify that this was what I did to begin with - and it worked, up until last week. The problem arose today when I did the exact same thing, and was told that the uploaded .apk was not zipAligned

Comment: Update: Tried downgrading to Android Studio 2.1.2 (stable channel), but again - no luck. The generated .apk is still not zipaligned, and aligning it fails in terminal, succeeds in APK signer but then fails again when uploading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, eureka!

I randomly stumbled upon this line in my root build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
```

Android Studio 2.2 preview 3 requires this gradle build tool upgrade, and I had just pressed "sure, go ahead" as always. I got curious, and tried to change it back to what had worked last,

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha2'
```

and built the project in Android Studio preview 2 instead - and voila, it worked! It seems there is a bug with the alpha3 build.

I hope this helps someone. I know I'm a happy friday-camper, that's for sure! :-)

Note to self: Don't rely on canary-builds for production apps in the future, no matter how much my friends and collegues push.

Comment: Note that I downgraded yet again to the stable 2.1.0 version, as some of my users (specifically Galaxy S5 users on Android 5.0) experienced the error described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354075/android-studio-2-2-preview-1-edittext-error

Comment: Not even if downgrading to 2.1.0? @Cliff

Comment: - Faced this issue today and finally had to revert to Android studio 1.5.1 with build grade set to  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0' . Never ever use preview builds for production!!

Comment: Changing to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha2' worked for me, struggled two days. Thanks alot.

Comment: AS won't even let me downgrade. After sync it brings up error and forces 2.1.3 again. How are you downgrading?

Comment: Sounds very wierd - you should just be able to specify the version of the build tool you want to use and resync Gradle. Something else might be fidgy. Have you tried restarting? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here are the things that I faced a few days ago: Try them one at a time:

- After downloading Android Studio 2.2 Preview 2 - which was released during the IO conference, I ran my code successfully until when time came to release a newer version of the apk to the playstore. That was when hell broke loose!
- I searched all over but I got nothing. So, someone suggested the following approach: After generating your signed apk, unzip it and delete `META-INF` folder then re-package it and manually sign it through the terminal. Packaging a file into `.apk` format is simple: just use a zip extension then rename the extension.
- Although that seemed like it could have worked for me, it didn't. It worked for others though.
- Finally, I realized that it was caused by a bug in the latest Android Studio Preview 2.
- Thankfully, I still had my stable 2.1 version which I opened, loaded my project and Boom! It worked like I expected it to.

So, please try the last option, clean up your project first then try again. I know how frustrating this can be. Good luck!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your contributions! Unfortunately, I had already tried downgrading to 2.1 without luck (and wrote in a comment on original post). I was about to try the META-INF approach when I stumbled upon the solution, which I'll write out seperately from this comment. 

Thanks, though! Really good suggestions, and I very much agree - there's nothing more frustrating than spending a whole day fighting build and deployment errors :-)

Comment: I am glad you finally figured out!