# Error inflating class EditText

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I get this weird error for no clear reason. I get it only when I use EditText, and when I replace EditText with TextView, no errors happen. I use EditText views in another activity just fine except for this one. Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/imgLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.45"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/streetImg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/blacktrans">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/locationName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/locationName"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/address"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
            android:background="@drawable/divider" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/opentxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Open"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/open"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/opentxt"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/costtxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Cost"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/costlayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/costtxt"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="/min"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distancetxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Distance"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/distancetxt"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/distance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/distancetxt"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" miles"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/controLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
    android:layout_weight="0.55"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/view_right_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/view_top_margin">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dateIcn"
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
        android:src="@drawable/srch_cal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dateEdit"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateIcn"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="Date"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/timeIcn"
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timeEdit"
        android:src="@drawable/srch_clock" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/timeEdit"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="Time"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rsrvfor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timeEdit"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Reserve for: "
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seekval"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timeEdit"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rsrvfor"
        android:text="10"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timeEdit"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seekval"
        android:text=" min"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/min120"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timeEdit"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="120 min"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timeEdit"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:max="110" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekbar"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="$"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5.0"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Pay and Reserve"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the stack trace

```
07-03 17:42:40.148 26088-26088/com.ridecell.app.ridecell E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.ridecell.app.ridecell, PID: 26088
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ridecell.app.ridecell/com.ridecell.app.ridecell.Activities.SpotInfoActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #192: Error inflating class EditText
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #192: Error inflating class EditText
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                           at com.ridecell.app.ridecell.Activities.SpotInfoActivity.onCreate(SpotInfoActivity.java:61)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6288)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                                        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/abc_edit_text_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020012
                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3735)
                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3603)
                                                                           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:762)
                                                                           at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3970)
                                                                           at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:987)
                                                                           at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:74)
                                                                           at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:70)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:60)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:56)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:112)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1008)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1067)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                           at com.ridecell.app.ridecell.Activities.SpotInfoActivity.onCreate(SpotInfoActivity.java:61) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6288) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                                        Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #24: <nine-patch> requires a valid 9-patch source image
                                                                           at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray(NinePatchDrawable.java:445)
                                                                           at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.inflate(NinePatchDrawable.java:401)
                                                                           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1150)
                                                                           at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:185)
                                                                           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1150)
                                                                           at android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable.inflate(InsetDrawable.java:105)
                                                                           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1150)
                                                                           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1063)
                                                                        at android.content.res.R
```

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look here:
[EditText error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354075/android-studio-2-2-preview-1-edittext-error)

Seems to be a problem with Android Studio version, not with your code as it is.